# Enable/disable form fields using a checkbox in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On my form asp net MVC c# I have these fields:

- `True/False` as checkbox
- `A` as `TextBoxFor` value required
- `B` as `TextAreaFor` value not required

I need when the checkbox `True/False` is checked:

- `A` value >>> not required and disable this field
- `B` value >>> required

Can you help me?

My code below

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group" style="background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow; border:3px solid; font-weight:bold;">
            <h5 style="font-weight: bold; text-indent: 20px;">
                True/False @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Truefalse, true)
            </h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.A)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.A, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @Class = "Mytextarea2", placeholder = "A" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.A, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.B)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.B, new { style = "width: 420px; height: 100px;", placeholder = "B" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, do not use the [Required] annotation for fields A and B.

In the js, add a onchange event for the checkbox. This code should enable/disable A/B.

When you call the js when you submit the form, write some front end validation code that checks the state of the box and if A/B textboxes are valid.

Lastly, take care of server side validation. There you can check the state of the model, and add similar logic that you wrote in the front end validation.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, on change method of checkbox you can just check weather checkbox is true and if checkbox value is true add disable attribute with the field you want to disable else remove disable attribute with that field.